# Unity Prevent playing a sound for all objects with the same name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the problem is that when I click on one object, all other objects (with the same name as that object) make a sound.

This is the code I'm using:

```
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (this.gameObject.name == "door")
        {
            anim.SetBool("open", !(anim.GetBool("open")));
            SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("door");
        }

        if (this.gameObject.name == "window")
        {
            anim.SetBool("open", !(anim.GetBool("open")));
            SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("window");
        }
    }  
}
```

How to prevent playing a sound for all objects?

Comment: I don't think that is related to this script. Because you already use `OnMouseOver`. Also you don't have to use `this`. gameObject already refers to that object to which script is attached. Either you have issues with your colliders or there is something wrong with your `SoundManagerScript`

Comment: Try to put a `Debug.Log(gameObject.name)` line in `OnMouseOver` method and see how many of them fire when you hover an object.

Comment: I did that and It shows only that object. Now i put if state for each object, but every time I press on the object, that sound gets more sounds haha. For example, I click on the door, first I hear 2 sounds, and then 4 etc. I really don't know.

Comment: In Sound script i'm using PlayOneShot() function.

Comment: Well another problem you are using `Input.GetMouseButton` so this will be called multiple times. You might consider changing it to `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`.

Comment: Well that worked, thank you!

Comment: @AliKanat you should make it an answer than ;)

Comment: @derHugo just converted thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer. The problem in the script is related to user input.

`Input.GetMouseButton` returns whether the given mouse button is held down. Therefore, your if statement is true while mouse is held down. This is the reason why you have some many sounds playing continuously because you `Input.GetMouseButton` returns true on several frames during the interaction .

Instead `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` should be used. Because it returns true on the frame the user pressed the given mouse button. It will return false when mouse is held down. Therefore, it will return true only once when mouse is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

you could always try and set up an array of these objects that contain the sound and then turn them off all at the same time.

```
public gameObject[] itemsWithSound;

for(int i = 0; i < itemsWithSound.length; i++)
{
     itemsWithSound.SoundManagerScript.StopSound();
}
```